# Buscar hoja por su nombre Google apps script

Tags: script

Soy un aficionado a GAS, apenas estoy haciendo algunos pequeños script, mi consulta es ¿Cómo puedo buscar una hoja por su nombre?; lo que estoy haciendo es tomar datos de una hoja, filtrarlos en un arreglo, crear una hoja nueva con nombre y pegar los datos, si la hoja ya existe solo pegar los datos.

Espero que puedan ayudarme, gracias de antemano.

Dejo el código que tengo hasta el momento; lo que no entiendo y obviamente algo estoy haciendo mal es que probando el if creo una hoja con el nombre Ruta manualmente y no se detiene en la primera condición sino que pasa al else y me salta el error que la hoja con dicho nombre ya existe.

Otra duda que tengo es que ¿si tengo que ordenar en filas el array antes de pegarlos a otra hoja? ya que cuando uso el looger.log las filas cargan una al lado de otra pero he visto que pueden hacer cargar en memoria una fila debajo de otra, ¿es necesario eso?, disculpen tantas preguntas pero me gustaría aprender GAS; gracias nuevamente por leerme.

```
function codigo() {
  
  let libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let hoja  = libro.getSheetByName('Prueba');
      
  let ufila   = hoja.getLastRow();
  let ucolum  = hoja.getLastColumn();

//FILTRO
let rango   = hoja.getRange(2, 1, ufila-1, ucolum).getValues();
let filtro  = rango.filter(function(item){

  return item[8] == 'NITRATO' && item[9] == 'SI';

});
  
// CREAR NUEVA HOJA SI NO EXISTIERA

if (libro.getSheetByName('Ruta') == 'Ruta'){

   libro.getSheetByName('Ruta').getRange(startRow, 1).setValue(fila);
    
 }else{
  
      libro.insertSheet('Ruta Alterna');
      libro.getSheetByName('Ruta Alterna').getRange(2, 1).setValue(filtro);
     }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado has ahora? Pon un fragmento de tú código para ver que estás haciendo y como te podríamos ayudar.

Comment: Gracias por el consejo, voy a poner le código hasta donde tengo,